# auto calculate total value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have form as shown in picture

[image]

what i need is, when i type/ change value in amount, it auto calculate sum at the bottom

also i don't want to let add any character...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `class="calc"` to each of your amount input fields and add `id="total"` to your total result element.

The jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.calc').change(function(){
        var total = 0;
        $('.calc').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() != '')
            {
                total += parseInt($(this).val());
            }
        });
        $('#total').html(total);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

and a sample HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" class="calc" value="">
<input type="text" class="calc" value="">
<input type="text" class="calc" value="">
<input type="text" class="calc" value="">
<input type="text" class="calc" value="">

<span id="total"></span>
```

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**
This one works better:

```
$('.amount').keyup(function() {
    var result = 0;
    $('#total').attr('value', function() {
        $('.amount').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() !== '') {
                result += parseInt($(this).val());
            }
        });
        return result;
    });
});
```

### You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/G5yaK/

```
$('.amount').change(function() {
    $('#total').attr('value', function() {
        var result = 0;
        $('.amount').each(function() {
            result += $(this).attr('value');
        });
        return result;
    });
});
```

You have to add a `class="amount"` to the input fields and `id="total"` to the last field

Comment: 1) you've to use parseInt(), 2) if val is empty you cant add this to the result 3) use $(this).val() istead of $(this).attr('value').

Answer (score 2):

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/merakli/vxXCK/4/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xml:lang="tr" lang="tr" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9" />
<style type="text/css">
<!-- 
html,body,div,span,h1,h2,h3,p,hr,br,img,form,input,ul,li,a {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0;
}
ul li {list-style:none;}
body {
 font-family:Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;
 color:#444;
 line-height:1.5em;
} 
#kapsayici {
background:#fff;
margin:10px auto;
width:960px;
border:1px solid #dfdfdf;
min-height: 700px;
}
input {
border:1px solid #dfdfdf;
}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.fn.fonkTopla = function() {
var toplam = 0;
this.each(function() {
   var deger = fonkDeger($(this).val());
   toplam += deger;
});
return toplam;
};


function fonkDeger(veri) {
    return (veri != '') ? parseInt(veri) : 0;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name^="fiyat"]').bind('keyup', function() {
   $('#toplam').html( $('input[name^="fiyat"]').fonkTopla());
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="kapsayici">

 <ul>
  <li><input type="text" name="fiyat[]" /></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="fiyat[]" /></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="fiyat[]" /></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="fiyat[]" /></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="fiyat[]" /></li>
 </ul>
Toplam: <span id="toplam"></span>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```